# XAMMP - How do turn on --with-imap-ssl

Tags: php, apache, xampp

How do I turn on --with-imap-ssl in XAMMP?
I'm on Mac.

Under my imap setting I have this
IMAP c-Client Version     2004

However, I think I also need to have the following option, which is not currently showing
SSL Support     enabled

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: You recompile the php binary.

Comment: Also can't I just do that somewhere from php.ini or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with XAMP you must recompile PHP and add --with-imap-ssl to the Configure Command.

If you don't know what you are doing I would recommend trying to find a prebuilt php binary with imap ssl built in.